# TypeError with HTML escaping in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I try to html escape a string

```
from html import escape
project_name_unescaped = Project.get('name').encode('utf-8')
project_name = escape(project_name_unescaped)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hosts.py", line 70, in <module>
     project_name = escape(bytes(project_name_unescaped))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/html/__init__.py", line 19, in escape
    s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I also tried it with the following, but still have the same error

```
project_name = escape(bytes(project_name_unescaped))
```

The strange thing is, I'm pretty sure this had worked before. Any ideas whats wrong or what I need to change to make it work again? Also I tried it before with

```
from cgi import escape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a little confusing. `html.escape` expects `s` to be `str`, not `bytes` as you would expect from the message.

Remove all encoding-related stuff and it will work

```
from html import escape
project_name_unescaped = Project.get('name')
project_name = escape(project_name_unescaped)
```

Comment: thanks that helped. I just wondered, because before I had to add the encoding as else it would fail without it. Maybe that was for python2 the case.

Comment: Well, yes, Python 3 changed string representations. But hard to tell, there wasn't even `html` module in standard library of Python 2.

Comment: I used cgi module before, just switched to html recently after I had the issue with python 3.